# How do you put a `Bluetooth` speaker in unpairing mode?

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

As we all know that Bluetooth speakers and headsets has a pairing mode option. Most of the times, it’s a button that you need to hold for a few seconds. But my device's button is not  working for some reason I can only turn On/Off my Bluetooth device.

**Is there any tool in Linux that I can use to turn on the pairing mode on my Bluetooth device just by using its `MAC` address.** The reason I want to do this is because it is already paired and when it turns on it's already connected to a already paired device but I want to pair a different device with it.

A lot of time I used `bluetoothctl connect <MAC_ADDR>` but it didn't work.

I'm on **Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS**.

Comment: No. If the button is broken there is nothing in the OS that can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Some bluetooth devices are not capable of pairing to two devices at once. This depends on the hardware of the bluetooth device, not your OS. If the bluetooth device can not pair to any new devices, then the way to solve this issue would be to *unpair* the bluetooth device from whatever it's connected to, or at least disconnect it, so it can enter pairing mode.

Comment: `then the way to solve this issue would be to unpair the bluetooth device from whatever it's connected to, or at least disconnect it, so it can enter pairing mode.` Well, this is my question, how to do the same? My button is broken... or I have to buy a new Bluetooth device...

Comment: @Ayush if the button is broken, you're stuck.